# android on new intent creating animations

Tags: android, animation, material-design

i was referring to the below particular design

http://i.imgur.com/2NQP1Yq.gif

I was able to do the shared element transition between the images and it works fine.
I have the design which works proper with the FAB button and co ordinate layout

But i am not sure on how the FAB button is animated and the rest of the view , it kind of like does a jquery style slidedown animation.

My intent to start from the activity is like so

```
Intent intent = new Intent(image.getContext(), AlbumActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("albumimage", item.getImage());
                ActivityOptionsCompat options =  ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((MainActivity)image.getContext(),image,"transition_album_cover");
                image.getContext().startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
```

And to receive it, nothing major stuff

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

I am not sure where exactly to start to animation like that so any insight would be really helpful guys.